# How to bypass response 503 with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some information for my assignment but return response 503 from https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/stocks/view/3182.

the code I am using is

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get('https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/stocks/view/'+stockcode[x],headers=headers)
```

is it any other way that I can bypass the response 503?

Answer (score 0):

Please do a curl request on the API in order to check if the API is functional or not, Keeping this in mind 503 is generally the error which means you're not getting anything from the respective URL.

Comment: do you able to get the 200 response for the link?

Comment: I guess the issue is you are trying to concatenate integer to str which is throwing you a typeError, what you can do is for your URL you can use the 'f-string' method.

Your URL would look something like this:
requests.get(
    f'https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/stocks/view/{stockcode[x]}', headers=headers)

Comment: not working. you can try scrape using this link https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/stocks/view/3182

Comment: i am using python 2.7

Comment: Use this: 

request.get('https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/stocks/view/%s' % stockcode[x], headers=headers)

Comment: did you try and it wrks?

Comment: very likely my IP is being blocked and thus return error 503